# Which archetype is used in netbeans 12.2

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I'm new to maven. In Netbeans 12.2 you can create a java with maven, web application.
All works great.  I am just trying to figure out which archetype is used there.
Does anyone know, or how to I find out. I'd like to use the archetype elsewhere.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes/netbeans-platform-app-archetype the netbeans-platform-app-archetype.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Cathers, I will have a look.

Comment: That site shows an xml format, what is the command line to generate the site? For example: `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=` I couldn't fine that on the link given, thanks.